# Polchinski's doubling trick for extending open string theory to the whole complex plane

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions, complex-numbers, analyticity

Open string theory can be described on the upper-half complex plane. To simplify the description of open string theory, Polchinski asserts (eq. 2.6.28 in his Vol. I String Theory book) that it is convenient to use the "**doubling trick**" where we extend the domain of the stress-tensor $T$ to the lower half plane by defining
$$ T_{zz} (z) = T_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} (\bar{z}'), \quad \mathrm{Im}(z) <0, \tag{2.6.28} $$
where $z' = \bar{z}$.

This is where I get confused. It seems like the notation $\bar{z}' = \bar{\bar{z}} = z$ is not accurate. This statement would imply $T_{zz} (z) = T_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} (z)$, which gives no relation between the upper and lower half planes. I think the correct statement is $$T_{zz} (z) = T_{\bar{z} \bar{z}} (\bar{z}).\tag{1}$$

I thought it was a typo, but later in his book, he states in a similar setup (eq. 6.3.9)
$$ \tilde{b}(\bar{z}) = b(z'), \quad \mathrm{Im}(z) > 0, \tag{6.3.9} $$
where again $z' = \bar{z}$. In my opinion, the correct statement here would be $ \tilde{b}(\bar{z}) = b(z)$.

Polchinski's generic pattern for relating the upper half plane described by $z$, $\mathrm{Im}(z) > 0$ and the lower half plane described by $z' = f(z)$, $\mathrm{Im}(z') < 0$ is to write $A_1(z) = A_2(\bar{z}')$, but for me the correct relation in general is $A_1(z) = A_2(z')$. It looks like we should remove the "bar" on the $z$'s in all these equations.

So my question is, did Polchinski make the same typo multiple times in his book, or am I misunderstanding his notation, and if so what am I missing?

Comment: His explanation is not the most straightforward. But if $T_{zz}$ is initially only defined on the upper half plane and $T_{\bar{z} \bar{z}}$ is initially only defined on the lower half plane, a prescription to extend their definitions would involve plugging the same complex number into each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: OP's eq. (1) is incorrect, while Polchinski's eq. (2.6.28) is correct. Since the holomorphic argument here lives in the upper half plane, then the anti-holomorphic argument lives in the lower half plane. Eq. (2.6.28) extends the holomorphic argument $z$ to the lower half plane, cf. above comment by Connor Behan.

Let us check how the prescription (2.6.28) plays out in the very next eq. (2.6.29):

$$ \begin{align}
L_m~=~~&\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\curvearrowleft} \left( dz~z^{m+1} T_{zz}(z)-d\bar{z}~\bar{z}^{m+1} T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}(\bar{z})\right)\cr\cr
~\stackrel{z=re^{i\theta}}{=}& r^{m+2}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi} \left(e^{i(m+2)\theta}T_{zz}(re^{i\theta}) +e^{-i(m+2)\theta} T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}(re^{-i\theta})\right)\cr\cr
~\stackrel{(2.6.28)}{=}& r^{m+2}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi} \left(e^{i(m+2)\theta}T_{zz}(re^{i\theta}) +e^{-i(m+2)\theta} T_{zz}(re^{-i\theta})\right)\cr\cr
~=~~& r^{m+2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi} e^{i(m+2)\theta}T_{zz}(re^{i\theta})\cr\cr
~\stackrel{z=re^{i\theta}}{=}& \oint_0 \frac{dz}{2\pi i} z^{m+1} T_{zz}(z), 
\end{align} \tag{2.6.29}$$
as it should.